# How does Stack Overflow serve 60 million page views?

Tags: discussion

How does Stack Overflow serve 60 million pageviews with 5 servers while Digg requires 500 servers to serve 200 million page views?

Comment: Old infos... 95 million: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html

Comment: Amongst our weaponry are such diverse elements as: fear, surprise, ruthless efficiency, an almost fanatical devotion to the Pope, and nice red uniforms

Comment: And [waffles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffle) :-)

Comment: Because digg sucks ass.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great difference in load when serving different types of content. Static, text based pages are very light, whereas active pages can impose a heavy load on a server.

The underlying data structure also plays a big part - using efficient techniques to load data from optimised databases for display can make a huge difference. Have a look at the [ServerFault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/), where various aspects are discussed.